# Strange Blue Circle with Arrows won't go away in 3D

Tags: graphics, 3d, processing

(I don't know if this is the right place to post this problem but I don't know where else to post it so here it is)

I've been having this issue for awhile now where there is a weird gray box with a blue circle that contains arrows. No matter what I do, it won't go away. It's way too hard to describe so I'll insert (I guess link) some images:

This is from Processing 3.2.1 with the 3D Renderer:

[image: img]

This is from Europa Universalis IV, launched from Steam:

[image: img]

Notice that there wasn't even any code in the screenshot from Processing.

For anyone unfamiliar with those games/programs, they are completely unrelated other than that they render in 3D.

Some extra bits of information about it:

- Never happens in 2D
- Always on the right side of window
- I don't remember what I was doing (or what game I was playing) when it started a few months ago. Maybe I accidentally pressed a key combination?
- It happens in a few other games like "the Sims 3."

Any help in solving this is greatly appreciated, even if it's just redirecting me to another site that the question would be more relevant/better placed on.

Comment: Either your computer is haunted, or you have a problem with your graphics card. Try updating all of your drivers and restarting your computer.

Comment: what kind of graphics card do you have?

Comment: @JayBuckman GEFORCE GTX 1060

Comment: looks like some kind of control added by some addon/plugin  does it change on mouse move/click over it? (something like those mouse wheel controls I hate so much). The position is also susspicious (center right of view)

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?